# Using Solve to find the horizontal tangents of a polar graph

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

So I'm trying to use Solve to find where the derivative of the polar graph is equal to 0, i.e horizontal, but it is saying it is too complex for Mathematica to solve? Also, how do I specify the domain for my argument? The documentation only shows specifying the domain for Reals, Complexes, etc but not a specific range of values, i.e $0<\theta<$2Pi

My Code:

```
f[theta_]:=Cos[2theta]
         dydx = (f'[theta_]*Sin[theta]+f[theta_]*Cos[theta])/(f'[theta_]*Cos[theta] - f[theta_]*Sin[theta])

         Solve[dydx == 0,theta]
```

Link to the problem: https://gyazo.com/66a660ec8f338b7c7742bd995005763e

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should have `Blank` (`_`) only in the definitions of functions. In `dydx` you're mixing `theta_` and `theta`; get rid of the `_` and it will work.

Comment: @corey979 That was very trivial! Thank you! Also, do you know how to specify a domain using solve aside from the very general Reals, Complexes, etc?

Comment: You should read the [docs of `Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). In particular, the fourth example under Basic Examples.

Comment: To extend what was stated by @corey979: Use `dydx = (f'[theta]*Sin[theta] + 
     f[theta]*Cos[theta])/(f'[theta]*Cos[theta] - 
     f[theta]*Sin[theta]);` Might also want to restrict range of `theta`, say using `Solve[dydx == 0 && 0 <= theta <= 2*Pi, theta]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
f[t_] := Cos[2 t];
r[t_] := f[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}
rd[t_] := r'[s]/Sqrt[r'[s].r'[s]] /. s -> t
h = {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[r[t]], Black, 
    Arrow[{r[t], r[t] + 0.2 rd[t]}]} /. 
   Solve[r'[t][[2]] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2 Pi, t];
PolarPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> h]
```

[image]